# mysql query to output rows to columns

Tags: mysql

I have the below query that works 100%.

```
SELECT
transporttype,
concat(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%m')), ' ', year) AS `month`,
round(sum(cost),0) AS cost
FROM v2ReportingTable
WHERE (transporttype not in ('Extrusions-LongDistance','Extrusions-Shuttle') and urgent='no')
GROUP BY (concat(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%m')),' ',year)),transporttype
ORDER BY (concat(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%m')),' ',year)), transporttype
```

This outputs the results in 1 column as below:

[image]

How can I manipulate the query so that the output is in columns, so I can graph it. desired output is like:

[image]

Help appreciated as always,

**Updated to match possible answer from Oscar Pérez**

[image]

Comment: Nothing visible here ... Where is `1 column as below:` and `output is like`?

Comment: It is a PIVOT table for your query. [Here is a good explanation how to do it.](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @JW, thanks for your assistance.

```
SELECT  `month`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN transporttype = 'Inbound' THEN loads ELSE NULL END) `Inbound`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN transporttype = 'LocalGauteng' THEN loads ELSE NULL END) `LocalGauteng`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN transporttype = 'LongDistance' THEN loads ELSE NULL END) `LongDistance`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN transporttype = 'Shuttle-company1' THEN loads ELSE NULL END) `Shuttle-company1`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN transporttype = 'Shuttle-company2' THEN loads ELSE NULL END) `Shuttle-company2`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN transporttype = 'stores' THEN loads ELSE NULL END) `stores`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN transporttype = 'returns' THEN loads ELSE NULL END) `returns`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN transporttype = 'localkzn' THEN loads ELSE NULL END) `localkzn`
FROM
    (
        SELECT  transporttype,
                CONCAT(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%m')), ' ', year) AS `month`,
                COUNT(loadnumber) AS loads
        FROM    v2ReportingTable
        WHERE   transporttype not in ('Extrusions-LongDistance','Extrusions-Shuttle') AND
                urgent='no'
        GROUP BY (concat(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%m')),' ',year)), transporttype
    ) aa
GROUP BY `month`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `LEFT JOIN` operator. For example:

```
SELECT s0.month, 
       s1.cost as Inbound, 
       s2.cost as LocalPMB,
       s3.cost as Shuttle,    
       s4.cost as LongDistance
  FROM (
         SELECT 1 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 2 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 3 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 4 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 5 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 6 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 7 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 8 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 9 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 10 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 11 as month
          UNION
         SELECT 12 as month
       ) as s0
LEFT JOIN
       (
         SELECT month,
                round(sum(cost),0) AS cost
           FROM v2ReportingTable
          WHERE urgent='no'
            AND transporttype='Inbound'
       GROUP BY month
       ) as s1 on s0.month=s1.month
LEFT JOIN
       (
         SELECT month,
                round(sum(cost),0) AS cost
           FROM v2ReportingTable
          WHERE urgent='no'
            AND transporttype='LocalPMB'
       GROUP BY month
       ) as s2 on s0.month=s2.month
LEFT JOIN
       (
         SELECT month,
                round(sum(cost),0) AS cost
           FROM v2ReportingTable
          WHERE urgent='no'
            AND transporttype='Shuttle'
       GROUP BY month
       ) as s3 on s0.month=s3.month
LEFT JOIN
       (
         SELECT month,
                round(sum(cost),0) AS cost
           FROM v2ReportingTable
          WHERE urgent='no'
            AND transporttype='Long Distance'
       GROUP BY month
       ) as s4 on s0.month=s4.month
ORDER BY month
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar, works well but not completely. if month 2,3,4, does not have data, the corresponding data for month 1 is not present as the joined column has no data? how can we force it to show all data from month 1 and only what data is available for month 2, month 3 etc. any ideas? outer join? Thanks, Ryan

Comment: Edited response. Now you'll get 12 rows and the corresponding columns. Every column will be empty for the months that it has no data

Comment: Hi, this only shows values for Inbound. as there are no values for the other 'transport types' it displays blank as per updated image on question...

Comment: Hi, I created a Fiddle to show this query with sample data... Just for curiosity: are not its results correct? You can see the Fiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c5ad/1